# How would you find the exact roots of $y=x^3+x^2-2x-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials, roots, cubics

My friend asked me what the roots of $y=x^3+x^2-2x-1$ was.

I didn't really know and when I graphed it, it had no integer solutions. So I asked him what the answer was, and he said that the $3$ roots were $2\cos\left(\frac {2\pi}{7}\right), 2\cos\left(\frac {4\pi}{7}\right)$ and $2\cos\left(\frac {8\pi}{7}\right)$.

> **Question:** How would you get the roots without using a computer such as Mathematica? Can other equations have roots in Trigonometric forms?

Anything helps!

Comment: See [the Wikipedia page.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function). There is a general method for producing these kinds of solutions. It's described in the section "General solution to the cubic with real coefficients"

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218441/generate-a-polynomial-w-integer-coefficients-whose-roots-are-rational-values-of

Comment: OP, does the graph cross the x-axis at all?

Comment: @moonman239 can you think of *any* cubic equation whose graph *doesn't* cross the x-axis at all?

Comment: @alephzero: Point taken.

Comment: in that case, @Frank, I suggest looking at the Irrational Root Theorem.

Comment: How is the Irrational Root Theorem going to help me solve the cubic in Trigonometric terms?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let $p(x) = x^3+x^2-2x-1$, we have $$p(t + t^{-1}) = t^3 + t^2 + t + 1 + t^{-1} + t^{-2} + t^{-3} = \frac{t^7-1}{t^3(t-1)}$$

The RHS has roots of the form $t = e^{\pm \frac{2k\pi}{7}i}$ 
( coming from the $t^7 - 1$ factor in numerator ) 
for $k = 1,2,3$. So $p(x)$ has roots of the form $$e^{\frac{2k\pi}{7} i} + e^{-\frac{2k\pi}{7} i} = 2\cos\left(\frac{2 k\pi}{7}\right)$$ for $k = 1,2,3$.

Comment: Why (out of all the integers), did you choose $k$ to equal $1,2,3$?

Comment: And how did you come up with this method? Is great! :D

Comment: @Frank, For any integer $k$, $e^{\frac{2k \pi}{7}i}$ is a root of $t^7 - 1$. 
Since $e^{2\pi i} = 1$, integers differs by a multiple of $7$ give us the same root. For the six roots of $\frac{t^7 - 1}{t-1} =t^6 + t^5 + t^4 + t^3 + t^2 + t + 1$, the corresponding $k$ can be any $6$ integers as long as
they are not divisible by $7$ and  belong to different equivalent class 
under modulo $7$ arithmetic. We can take $k$ to be $1,2,3,4,5,6$, we can also take them to be $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3$. I pick the later one because it is more convenient to combine the exponentials to cosines.

Comment: @Ant, we are told the roots are $2\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{7}\right)$, the simplest way to get them are $2\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{7}\right) = e^{\frac{2k\pi}{7}i} + e^{-\frac{2k\pi}{7}i}$, the natural guess is substitute $x = t + t^{-1}$ in $p(x)$ and see what one get. As one expect, it is a polynomial for all the primitive $7$ roots of unity.

Comment: Wait, so how did you know to substitute $x$ with $t+\frac {1}{t}$? It's either I'm not putting two and two together, or I forgot some important detail. :/

Comment: @Frank by experience, there are not too many ways to construct $\cos z$ from something even simpler, $\cos z = e^{iz} + e^{-iz}$ is one. In general, if you are given a real polynomial whose roots are very simple trigonometry functions, you should try to see whether you can express them in terms of a single root of unity.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the help!

Comment: By the way, do you know any other polynomial equations whose roots are trigonometric functions?

Comment: As a start, lookup [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) on wiki. Most equations like this can be build from one or two Chebyshev polynomials. e.g. the current polynomial is $\frac{T_4(x/2)-T_3(x/2)}{x/2-1}$ (first pointed out by J.M in comment in David's answer).

Comment: Is it possible to let $x=a\cdot\cos(b)$ and solve it from there?

Comment: @Frank, It is possible but dealing with trigonometic identities is usually harder, you basically don't know which identities to use. If you do it through polynomials, you have a small list (Chebyshev polynomails) to check and see whether there is something that can be used to simplify the expression.

Comment: Using your substitution method, I solved $y=x^3-3x-1$ with roots $2\cos\left(\frac {\pi}{9}\right), 2\cos\left(\frac {5\pi}{9}\right)$ and $2\cos\left(\frac {7\pi}{9}\right)$

Answer (score 9):

Consider the equation $$\cos4\theta=\cos3\theta$$ whose roots are $$\theta=n\cdot\frac{2\pi}{7}$$

Representing this as a polynomial in $c=\cos\theta$, we have $$8c^4-4c^3-8c^2+3c+1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (c-1)(8c^3+4c^2-4c-1)=0$$

Now write $x=2c$ and we see that the polynomial equation $$x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$ has roots as stated in your question. Note that $$2\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}=2\cos\frac{8\pi}{7}$$

Comment: +1 for the $2\cos\frac{6\pi}{7} = 2\cos\frac{8\pi}{7}$ part.

Comment: In the language of Chebyshev polynomials: $\frac{T_4(x/2)-T_3(x/2)}{x/2-1}$ is the polynomial under consideration.

Answer (score 7):

Set $x=t+t^{-1}$. Then the equation becomes
$$
t^3+3t+3t^{-1}+t^{-3}+t^2+2+t^{-2}-2t-2t^{-1}-1=0
$$
and, multiplying by $t^3$,
$$
t^6+t^5+t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1=0
$$
and it should be now clear what the solutions are. For each root there's another one giving the same solution in $x$.